# Cannot not find "calc.RL.0" function within "mixstock" package

Tags: r, function, package, markov-chains

I am trying to run through a mixed stock analysis in RStudio based on the walkthrough provided by Bolker (https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=043730a02b148396ebd54b2f62e8f6364714b1b2), using the '`mixstock`' package and the example '`lahanas98raw`' dataset within. However, I am receiving a warning that the '`calc.RL.0`' function cannot be found whilst trying to carry out Raftery and Lewis convergence diagnostics (p.14 of Bolker's walkthrough). I am wondering whether one of the packages has not installed properly (i.e., either '`mixstock`' or '`coda`'), or whether there is another package I can use to run this diagnostic instead.

When I initially tried to install the '`mixstock`' package, the following warning came up:
'`Warning in install.packages :  package ‘mixstock’ is not available for this version of R.`'
I tried installing the version of R (2.14.1) described as the 'current version of R' on page 2 of Bolker's walkthrough, but when I then tried to switch to this version of R in RStudio via the options menu, it says that this version of R is not compatible with RStudio. To work around this, I downloaded the '`mixstock`' package (version 0.9.5.1) from the CRAN archive (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mixstock/) and uploaded it to RStudio this way instead.

This seemed to have worked, as I successfully ran through a significant amount of the code, but a new error arose when I tried to run Raftery and Lewis convergence diagnostics (p.14). When I try to run `calc.RL.0(mydata)`, I receive the following error:
'`Error in calc.RL.0(mydata) : could not find function "calc.RL.0"`'
However, when I click on '`mixstock`' in the package window, everything seems fine and the '`calc.RL.0`' function appears, alongside several other 'calc' functions (e.g. '`calc.GR`', '`calc.mult.GR`', '`calc.mult.RL`') that can all be found and run fine. The '`calc.RL.0`' function relies on the '`raftery.diag`' function within the '`coda`' package, so I have also made sure that is installed and called. I have tried a bunch of other methods but nothing seems to be working.

Here is some of my code leading up to the warning message:

```
## Calculate confidence intervals - i.e., bootstrapping - and plot them
mydata.umlboot = genboot(mydata,"uml")
confint(mydata.umlboot)
plot(mydata.umlboot, ylim=c(0,1))

## Carry out Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) estimations and plot them
mydata.mcmc = tmcmc(mydata)
mydata.mcmc
confint(mydata.mcmc)
plot(mydata.mcmc, ylim=c(0,1))

## Check that the Markov chains have converged = run Raftery and Lewis diagnostics
library(mixstock)
library(coda)
calc.RL.0(mydata)
    'Error in calc.RL.0(mydata) : could not find function "calc.RL.0"'
```

Could this be something to do with the way the '`mixstock`' package was initially installed, or is it likely to be another issue? Is there another way to run Raftery and Lewis diagnostics and still get the outputs I need (diagnostics for the last chain evaluated; the history of how long each suggested chain was)? Any help would be much appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to install `mixstock`, if you have development tools installed on your computer (compilers etc.), is `remotes::install_github("bbolker/mixstock")` (I don't think I've changed anything/fixed any bugs since the archived version, but if I did the changes would be reflected on GitHub.)

It looks like I forgot to export that function, so

```r
mixstock:::calc.RL.0(mydata)
```

should work (this is something I can/should fix). Note that the Gelman-Rubin diagnostic (`calc.GR()`, which *is* properly exported) is more reliable than Raftery-Lewis anyway ...